# Youtube API get video file or sound

Tags: android, audio, video, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API in my android app,and everything works good.
Right now I have a search engine which search videos in youtube,I want to get the sound of the video when I choose a video from the search list.
I used this code to search in youtube:

```
ntent intent;
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createSearchIntent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Zach");
    startActivity(intent);
```

It's from their sample,I need this for myself use.
I also there is a way to use link with their DATA API like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<video_id>&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&part=snippet
```

But it works with video id not a search list or something.